# Is there a PGP/GPG Plugin for TextWrangler?

Tags: security, encryption, text-editor, gpg

Is there a PGP/GPG plugin for TextWrangler? If so, what is it called and how do I go about downloading and installing it?

Comment: and/or for BBedit?